# Efficient way to get a reversed copy of std::string

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, c++17

Dealing with algorithmic tasks I frequently need to get a copy of reversed `std::string`. Also, the source string should not be modified. As far as I concerned, there are two ways to do it:

1. Use `std::reverse` :

```
// std::string sourceString has been initialized before.
std::string reversedString = sourceString;
std::reverse(reversedString.begin(), reversedString.end());
```

2. Use reverse iterators. This one I found on the Internet:

```
// std::string sourceString has been initialized before.
std::string reversedString{sourceString.rbegin(), sourceString.rend()};
```

My question is which approach I should prefer according to efficiency and best practices.
C-style solutions are not in my concern, I am only interested in STL-way approaches.

Comment: Efficiency can be a lot of things so you need to specify it. Do you want the algorithm to be fast? Or do you want it to use as little memory as possible? Do you only need to output the reverse string or do you need to store it?

Comment: To reverse the characters in a string, you're going to have to read all the characters and write them into a new position (except possibly in the special case of the middle character in an odd-length string).  You can do that with N/2 swaps (which is what std::reverse does), or N copies (which is what creating a new string does).

Comment: Both approaches shown deal with individual `char`s only. Neither one handles multi-byte characters correctly, ie non-ASCII characters that use 2+ `char`s in a MBCS/UTF-8 string. In that case, you would have to iterate `sourceString` forwards, calculating and extracting complete `char` sequences to then insert as-is into the front of `reversedString` one at a time, thus protecting the integrity of each sequence, changing only the order of sequences in relation to other sequences.

Comment: Why do you *need* an efficient method for reversing a string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is which approach I should prefer according to efficiency

The one which should be preferred according to efficiency is the one that has been measured to be more efficient. Both have the same asymptotic complexity.

But, I won't bother to measure the difference unless it happens to be a bottleneck. I prefer 2, but it's subjective.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So, from the point of best practices, there are no difference between this two ways?

Comment: @powercat They're implemented slightly different, so one might be faster or slower, but it would depend on your compiler, settings, and cpu. It might even be that one is faster on fast computers, and the other is faster on slow computers.

Comment: @powercat: From the point of view of best practices... it's highly unlikely that the time it takes to reverse the characters in a string will be a problem for your program's performance.

Comment: @powercat the [as-if rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if) says the compiler is allowed to do whatever it wants  so long as the observable behaviour does not change. That means the compiler is within its rights to swap 1 for 2, 2 for 1, or either for a 3 you haven't even thought of.

Comment: Doubling down on Nicol's advice.  Micro-optimizations should only be worried about after profiling has shown that there is a performance problem for that hot path in the code.

Answer (score 3):

I could say that constructing a data structure with the right data initially is faster generally, but general statements about performance is generally wrong. You should measure the performance and benchmark if you're concerned about performance.

If you're not concerned enough about performance to write benchmark code, then you should take the style that looks the best for you.

---

Also, you forgot C++20 style:

```
auto reversed = sourceString | std::views::reverse;
std::string reversedString{begin(reversed), end(reversed)};
```

Which in the end is not that different from the iterator range style since the string still need a iterator pair.

Answer (score 1):

Like others have said you should first decide what is more meaningful to your code-base, style or speed. If style, just use `std::reverse` which has an average runtime of O(n). If speed is a bottleneck and you run this reverse string method all the time, I would consider creating a doubly-linked list. Then reversing the LL can happen in O(1) runtime.